# How can I identify coefficients for a multiple polynomial regression using sklearn coef_ attribute?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

after performing a multiple polynomial regression with Python (I am trying to have a RPM expression for my engine depending on air density, air intake density and true air speed) I am getting the following coefficients from the (lm.coef_) attribute:
`Coefs : [ 0.00000000e+00 -6.51144696e+03  2.01556735e+03 -9.72906080e+00 -4.13397298e+03  1.02856530e+04  1.91315571e+01 -4.36122986e+03 -1.50183017e+01  2.44236867e-02]`

I would like to now which coefficient corresponds to which term, but I cant find the answer anywhere.

I guess it should be (my three features are ro_air, ro_mot and tas):
`ro_air * (-6.51144696e+03) + ro_mot * (2.01556735e+03) + tas * (-9.72906080e+00) + (-4.13397298e+03) * ro_air*ro_mot + ro_air * tas * (1.02856530e+04) + ro_mot*tas  * (1.91315571e+01) + ro_air * ro_air * (-4.36122986e+03) + ro_mot * ro_mot * (-1.50183017e+01) + tas * tas * (2.44236867e-02) + 5408.887942581865`
But when I try to evaluate it I get crazy RPM values so I guess coefficient are in the wrong order.